# Grounding wire from 2 Ground Rods to Main Panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Question:  Do I need to run 2 grounding wires to the electrical panel for 2 grounding rods, or can I connect the 2 grounding wires and run only 1 grounding wire to the electrical panel?  If I can use only 1 grounding wire to the electrical panel; at what distance from the grounding rod connection would I connect the second grounding wire to the first grounding wire?  Also, what type of connector should I use to connect the 2 grounding wires?

I have a 200 amp panel in a new construction home.  The state inspector says I need 2 grounding rods for the panel.

Comment: Location is needed for accurate answer. If you include State/Province users may know if your locality adopts rules in excess or exceptions to the national Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you use one continuous run of wire from the panel to both rods, the NEC only allows splicing by exothermic welding or irreversible crimp splices that aren't typically available to a homeowner. You can run two separate wires, but usually that requires more wire and more penetrations to create and seal.

Probably 99% of connections use the same style [ground rod connector](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=GRC-50&t=vivaldi&iax=images&ia=images).

Place the first rod as close to the panel as practically possible. The NEC requires minimum 6' spacing between rods, but check with your local inspector to make sure they don't require greater spacing. Also check to make sure they don't require larger conductor size than the #6 copper allowed by the NEC.

Since you may mushroom the rod when driving the rod set the connector firmly on the rod before driving. After driving the first rod full length loosen the connector and slide enough wire through it to reach the second rod.

Comment: Yeah -- while there's nothing that *prohibits* you from using irreversible compression or exothermic splicing methods as a DIYer, compression tooling for that size wire/splice isn't very cheap, and exothermic methods are a bit of a faff since you're basically lighting a little thermite ball on fire inside a graphite mold (aka, the tooling's not cheap for those either)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Saw a brand new mold fail once, tapping onto grounding electrode conductor at a telco CO. That little thermite ball left about 4 strands of the 750 intact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NoSparksPlease.  Let me make sure that I understand what you are telling me to do.  1 Drive first grounding rod as close to the panel as possible; with connector on the rod.  2 Drive second grounding rod 6' away with connector on the rod.  3 Using #6 bare copper wire make a run from the panel to the first grounding rod, feeding through connector, continuing on to second grounding rod and fastening to the grounding with connector.  4 Check with inspector to make sure #6 bare copper wire is large enough/permitted for this application; BEFORE DOING THE WORK.  Correct?

Comment: Also, I live in LaGrange Maine; a small town.  There is not a town code; that is why I am using the State Inspector.

Comment: @Iborn Yes, and it looks like Maine makes no amendments to NEC Article 250 where grounding questions arise.  https://www.maine.gov/pfr/professionallicensing/sites/maine.gov.pfr.professionallicensing/files/inline-files/ElectricalStandardsRule_0.pdf

Comment: @NoSparksPlease again thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I realize this is an old question/answer, but the grounding conductor can be run from the rods to a water pipe (within 5ft of entrance), and a separate conductor run from the meter to the water pipe, is that correct?

Comment: @000 Yes, I believe that is the intent of 250.64(C) deferring to 250.68, but personally really think water pipe clamps have too many  parts that can be points of failure and wouldn't normally install that way. I really think this is a legacy section that goes back to when water pipes became unacceptable as the single electrode. This section allows improving existing installations where a new EGC to ground rods is impractical.

Comment: @000 please take the [tour]. You'll be reminded that this isn't a discussion forum. That would be much better off as a whole new question.